# What is the best way to handle functional django model field defaults?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-migrations

Sometimes a ForeignKey field needs a default. For example:

```
class ReleaseManager(BaseManager):

    def default(self):
        return self.filter(default=True).order_by('-modified').first()


class Release(BaseModel):
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...


class Server(models.Model):
    ...
    release = models.ForeignKey(Release, null=True, default=Release.objects.default)
```

All is well and good with the above code until the time comes for db migration whereupon the functional default causes big problems because the default function cannot be serialized. Manual migration can work around this but on a large project where migrations are perhaps [squashed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) periodically this leaves a time bomb for the unwary.

A common workaround is to move the default from the field to the save method of the model but this causes confusion if the model is used by things like the [rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) or in creating forms where the default is expected on the field.

Answer (score 0):

My current favourite workaround works with migrations and with the rest framework and other form generation. It assumes the object manager supplies a default method and uses a specialized ForeignKey field to get at it:

```
class ForeignKeyWithObjectManagerDefault(models.ForeignKey):

    def __init__(self, to, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(to, **kwargs)
        self.to = to

    def get_default(self):
        return self.to.objects.default().pk


class Project(SOSAdminObject):
    primary = ForeignKeyWithObjectManagerDefault(Primary, related_name='projects')
    ...
```

Now migrations work as expected and we can use any functionality we like to supply a default object to a foreign key field.